# Pyglet не работает пауза python 3.7, Pyside2

Tags: python

я хочу сделать mp3 player на python3 (3.7.2),
вот вроде-бы идет нормально но вот с паузой проблема она не работает вообще,нигде не нашел ответа,в других тоже не работает пауза использую я pyglet.
Мой код:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ui import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
import os
import pyglet
import pygame

#Start app
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#Create UI Form
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

#Hook logic
def playsound () :
    sound = pyglet.media.load('sound.mp3')
    sound.play()
    pyglet.app.run()

def stopsound ():
    pyglet.app.exit

ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect( stopsound )
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect( playsound )
#Run Main Loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Зачем вам pyglet, если PySide2 сам через QMediaPlayer сможет воспроизвести музыку?

Comment: Попробуйте оформить функцию `stopsound` так: `def stopsound(): pyglet.app.exit()`. Обратите внимание на `()` после `exit`.

Comment: S. Nick,нет я пытался ставить их не получилось

Comment: @TriOnixChannel во-первых - добавьте скобки к `exit`, как показал S. Nick (если не добавить скобки, вызов метода `exit` точно не произойдет), во-вторых - запустите из консоли и посмотрите какие ошибки пишет, если пишет